# Simple - Injective function

Tags: functions

Define $F: \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{N}$ by $f(x) = (3x-1)^2 + 1$.  Prove that F is injective.

Definition of a injective function is: A function $F: D \to  T$ is injective if and only if $\forall x, y \in D$ if $f(x) = f(y)$ if it follows that $x = y.$

I am confused about how to use this definition to solve this proof.

Comment: Based on equality $(3x-1)^2+1=(3y-1)^2+1$ it must be shown that $x=y$. This for $x,y\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: The "usual" first step in this type of question is to assume $F(n_{1}) = F(n_{2})$, and to try to prove $n_{1} = n_{2}$ (or find a counterexample, if you aren't sure whether $F$ is injective).

Comment: You can also try to prove the contrapositive: a function is injective if and only if for all $ x, y \in \mathbb Z$ such that $x\neq y$, we have  $f(x) \neq f(y)$. If, however, you find particular values $x, y$ such that $x\neq y$ but $f(x) = f(y)$, then you've got a counterexample which would prove a function is not injective.

Comment: Do you remember: $A^2-B^2=(A+B) (A-B)$ ? Is useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start with $f(x)=f(y)$

$(3 x-1)^2+1=(3 y-1)^2+1$.

But this is the same as

$(3 x-1)^2-(3 y-1)^2=0$.

Now you may use: $A^2-B^2=(A+B) (A-B)$.

You will get:

$3 (3 (x+y)-2) (x-y)=0$.

This factor can't be zero, 
$3 (x+y)-2$

because $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$.

So $x-y$ has to be zero, which means

$x=y$. And we are done.